# Nokogiri text node contents

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Is there any clean way to get the contents of text nodes with Nokogiri?  Right now I'm using

```
some_node.at_xpath( "//whatever" ).first.content
```

which seems really verbose for just getting text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want *only* the text?

```
doc.search('//text()').map(&:text)
```

Maybe you don't want all the whitespace and noise. If you want only the text nodes containing a word character,

```
doc.search('//text()').map(&:text).delete_if{|x| x !~ /\w/}
```

Edit: It appears you only wanted the text content of a single node:

```
some_node.at_xpath( "//whatever" ).text
```

Comment: Just a followup: if you want to find all nonblank text nodes and you are using Rails, then you have the `present?` and `blank?` methods. Each of these are equivalent: `doc.search('//text()').map(&:text).delete_if &:blank?` or `doc.search('//text()').map(&:text).keep_if &:present?`

Comment: Or, more simply, `some_node.at('whatever').text`.

Comment: The `delete_if`/`keep_if` code doesn't actually work, because these methods delete from the array created by `map` and not from the `NodeSet` returned by `search`.

Answer (score 9):

Just look for text nodes:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<body>
<p>This is a text node </p>
<p> This is another text node</p>
</body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('//text()').each do |t|
  t.replace(t.content.strip)
end

puts doc.to_html
```

Which outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>This is a text node</p>
<p>This is another text node</p>
</body></html>
```

BTW, your code example doesn't work. `at_xpath( "//whatever" ).first` is redundant and will fail. `at_xpath` will find only the first occurrence, returning a Node. `first` is superfluous at that point, if it would work, but it won't because Node doesn't have a `first` method.

---

> I have `<data><foo>bar</foo></bar>`, how I get at the "bar" text without doing `doc.xpath_at( "//data/foo" ).children.first.content`?

Assuming `doc` contains the parsed DOM:

```
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<data>\n  <foo>bar</foo>\n</data>\n"
```

Get the first occurrence:

```
doc.at('foo').text       # => "bar"
doc.at('//foo').text     # => "bar"
doc.at('/data/foo').text # => "bar"
```

Get all occurrences and take the first one:

```
doc.search('foo').first.text      # => "bar"
doc.search('//foo').first.text    # => "bar"
doc.search('data foo').first.text # => "bar"
```

Comment: Uh, sorry, I meant children.first.content.  Your example isn't exactly what I want, though - let's say I have <data><foo>bar</foo></bar>, how I get at the "bar" text without doing doc.xpath_at( "//data/foo" ).children.first.content?

Comment: It's *really* important to be clear about what you want. We can't help you otherwise. See the added content.

Comment: I thought I was - I thought xpath_at made it pretty clear I knew exactly the nodes I was looking for and was just getting their contents in a stupid way.